# Addition with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I current have a class in Javascript to handle a cart (only with static data as it stands). However, when I try to add two integers together:

```
var Cart = {
  handler: {
    totalCost: 0,

    addCost: function() {
      $('#cart li').each(function() {
        var cost = +$(this).attr('cost');
        console.log('single cost: ' + cost);
        var total = this.totalCost + cost;
        console.log('after add: ' + total);
      });
      console.log(this.totalCost);
    }
  }
};
```

I get this output:

```
after add: NaN
```

I have tried ensuring both values are numerical adding a `+` delimiter to the variable, I receive the same output? A sample of working code is at [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6kccr88/1/).

Comment: You can't expect us to help if you don't show us where `this.totalCost` and `cost` are coming from, can you?

Comment: I said, a sample of the code is at [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6kccr88/1/)... @ScottMarcus

Comment: you can use `this ` in methods

Comment: you are facing a scoping issue here

Comment: their `this` value will be element

Comment: I am inside the `each()` loop, yes @empiric can I get the parent scope using `parent` ? or directly access it through the `Cart.handler.totalCost` ?

Comment: yes, `Cart.handler.totalCost` is correct here. But have a second look at your code, you never update the value of `Cart.handler.totalCost`, have a look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/d6kccr88/4/)

Comment: `var total = Cart.handler.totalCost + cost;`

Comment: `Cart.handler.totalCost = +$(this).attr('cost') + Cart.handler.totalCost;` ?? @empiric I see the scope issue now because the `each(function()` is creating its own method scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scoping issue - within the each function this no longer refers to handler, but to the currently iterated element.  You can fix this by referring directly to Cart.handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var Cart = {
    handler: {

      productId: 'pid-',
      totalCost: 0,
      yesNoAlert: $('.display'),

      addCost: function() {
        $('#cart li').each(function() {
          cost = +$(this).attr('cost');
          console.log('single cost: ' + cost);
          total = Cart.handler.totalCost + cost;
          console.log('after add: ' + total);
        });
        console.log(Cart.handler.totalCost);
      },
      removeProduct: function(pid) {
        this.productId = pid;
        this.displayYesNo('remove');
      },
      displayYesNo: function(callback) {
        this.yesNoAlert.attr('callback', callback);
        this.yesNoAlert.slideToggle('slow');
      },
      callback: function(callback) {
        if (callback === 'remove') {
          $('#' + this.productId).hide();
        }
        this.yesNoAlert.hide();
      },
      throw: function(e) {
        $('#error').html(e);
        $('#error').slideToggle('slow');
      }

    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/d6kccr88/3/

you can save the value of this in another variable `that`  and use `that` variable in your method to save the `this` value

because in jquery each method the value of `this` will be your currect element which are currently iterating